# How can I bind a background color in WPF/XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, background

What do I have to change to the following code so that the background is red, neither of the 2 ways I tried worked:

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantsart.com](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1okq25l.png))</sub>

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestBackground88238.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}">
            <TextBlock.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Background}"/>
            </TextBlock.Background>
        </TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBackground88238
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region ViewModelProperty: Background
        private string _background;
        public string Background
        {
            get
            {
                return _background;
            }

            set
            {
                _background = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Background");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ViewModelProperty: Message
        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }

            set
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
        #endregion



        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Background = "Red";
            Message = "This is the title, the background should be " + Background + ".";

        }

        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

## Update 1:

I tried Aviad's answer which didn't seem to work. I can do this manually with x:Name as shown here but I want to be able to bind the color to a INotifyPropertyChanged property, how can I do this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantsart.com](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/7tp48m.png))</sub>

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestBackground88238.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Message2" Text="This one is manually orange."/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestBackground88238
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region ViewModelProperty: Background
        private Brush _background;
        public Brush Background
        {
            get
            {
                return _background;
            }

            set
            {
                _background = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Background");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ViewModelProperty: Message
        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }

            set
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            Message = "This is the title, the background should be " + Background + ".";

            Message2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

        }

        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309271/wpf-bind-background-color-of-datagridtextcolumn-to-color-by-row

Answer (score 68):

**Important:**

Make sure you're using `System.Windows.Media.Brush` and not `System.Drawing.Brush`

They're not compatible and you'll get binding errors.

The color enumeration you need to use is also different

> System.Windows.Media.Colors.Aquamarine  (class name is `Colors`)    <--- use this one
>   
>   System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine  (class name is `Color`)

If in doubt use `Snoop` and inspect the element's background property to look for binding errors - or just look in your debug log.

Comment: Please note that `System.Windows.Media.Colors` namespace returns a `System.Windows.Media.Color` with no `s`.

Comment: "Make sure you're using System.Windows.Media.Brush and not System.Drawing.Brush" this phrase helped

Answer (score 29):

The `Background` property expects a `Brush` object, not a string. Change the type of the property to `Brush` and initialize it thus:

```
Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work for me, I posted the code above (update 1)

Comment: be sure to use SolidColorBrush from System.Windows.Media and not SolidBrush from System.Drawing

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party but it's Colors.Red, not Color.Red. Was a bit confused by your answer till I found that one out.

Comment: The simplest variant in such case is to use predefined solid color brushes

Background = Brushes.Red    //System.Windows.Media

Comment: A frustrating and easily missed concept: `<TextBlock Background="{Binding TheBackground}"/>` was asked and needs the `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` namespace. If you need opacity and so use <TextBlock><TextBlock.Background>`<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding TheBackground}"` Opacity="{Binding TheOpacity}"/></TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>, you need `System.Windows.Media.Color` namespace. This answer shows how to convert between the two.

Answer (score 8):

Here you've got a copy-paste code:

```
class NameToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value.ToString() == "System")
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Aqua);
            }else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changing from using raw colors to using SolidColorBrush solved it for me. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out, it was just a **naming conflict issue**: if you use **TheBackground** instead of **Background** it works as posted in the first example. The property Background was interfering with the Window property background.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend reading the following blog post about debugging data binding: http://beacosta.com/blog/?p=52

And for this concrete issue: If you look at the compiler warnings, you will notice that you property has been hiding the Window.Background property (or Control or whatever class the property defines).

Comment: yes, the compiler warning was how I discovered it, thanks for the link, good information there

Comment: Unfortunately that link no longer works, do you know about a similar post? Thanks

Comment: @Ouissal https://web.archive.org/web/20151215181325/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486

Answer (score 2):

The xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Message2">
   <TextBlock Text="This one is manually orange."/>
</Grid>
```

The c# code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateNewColorBrush();
    }

    private void CreateNewColorBrush()
    {

        SolidColorBrush my_brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 215, 0));
        Message2.Background = my_brush;

    }
```

This one works in windows 8 store app. Try and see. Good luck !

Comment: The simplest variant in such case is to use predefined solid color brushes Background = Brushes.Red //System.Windows.Media

Answer (score 2):

You assigned a string "Red". Your Background property should be of type Color:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBackground88238
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region ViewModelProperty: Background
        private Color _background;
        public Color Background
        {
            get
            {
                return _background;
            }

            set
            {
                _background = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Background");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //...//
}
```

Then you can use the binding to the SolidColorBrush like this:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    Background = Colors.Red;
    Message = "This is the title, the background should be " + Background.toString() + ".";

}
```

not 100% sure about the .toString() method on Color-Object. It might tell you it is a Color-Class, but you will figur this out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use "Background" as the property name, as long as you give your window a name and use this name on the "Source" of the Binding.