# WPF - How to bind to a color in resources with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, caliburn.micro

How do I bind something like `<Color x:Key="SomeColor" />` to a dependency property with Caliburn Micro?

I need to be able to change `Color` at run-time and have it immediately updated in all things that use it.

## Solution:

---

XAML in SomeClassView.xaml

```
<SomeControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlBrush" />
</SomeControl.Resources>
```

---

C# in SomeClassViewModel.cs

```
[Export(typeof(MainWindowViewModel))]
public class MainWindowViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private SolidColorBrush _controlBrush;

    public SolidColorBrush ControlBrush
    {
        get { return _controlBrush; }
        set
        {
            _controlBrush = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ControlBrush);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem was exactly what Charleh said, I just totally forgot that not everything in WPF can be a DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't usually directly bind a `Color` object, you need to use a `SolidColorBrush` (for solid colour), as that's what most UI objects expect.

e.g.

`TextBox.Background` expects `Brush`, of which `SolidColorBrush` is a subclass of. There are other types of brushes that produce different fills such as `LinearGradientBrush`

Have a look here:

[How can I bind a background color in WPF/XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962149/how-can-i-bind-a-background-color-in-wpf-xaml)

Can you provide some screenshots of what you expect and the XAML?

**Edit:**

Ok well what you want is pretty simple to achieve, not really related to Caliburn.Micro at all :)

Create your styles as usual, but bind the brushes `Color` property dynamically using `DynamicResource`. When you update the colour itself, the resource binding will be evaluated again and the colours will change.

Example XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="TestColor" A="255" R="255" G="0" B="0"></Color>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource TestColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">Red</Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">Blue</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Resources["TestColor"] = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Resources["TestColor"] = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think examples are necessary, I'm sure once you hear what it's for you'll know. Basically I would have a set of styles for all controls and those styles would be different only in a couple of colors that they use. Instead what I want to do is have a single style and dynamically change some of the colors that it uses. So what I thought would be best is if I could auto-bind the `Color` object from resources to a dependency property so that it gets updated when I change it in code (or through a two-way binding) and the style would automatically get updated as well.

Comment: Edited to include an answer which should work for you - let me know if this isn't what you wanted

Comment: Haha, I see we both went different ways. I'll study your code and see how you do it.

Comment: Pretty much same thing - how did you get a hold of the resource in the VM though, because CM discourages the manipulation of the view directly from the VM

Comment: Exactly what you see is what I'm using. CM binds the named resource to a dependency property that I then change. What am I doing wrong here, how would you change it?

Comment: Ah, yes of course CMs conventions would bind this for you, kind of forgot about that haha (look at number of questions I've answered in CM tag!) - looks good to me!

Comment: Well I'm glad we cleared that out, I was a little bit worried for a while there. ;)