# How does a XAML attribute bind to a INotifyPropertyChanged object

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

have a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface like this:

```
public class ColorNotify : INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private SolidColorBrush bindableColor;
    public SolidColorBrush BindableColor
    {
        get { return bindableColor; }
        set
        {
            bindableColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BindableColor");
        }
    }  

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));   
        } 
    } 
}
```

One of the fields in my MainPage.xaml.cs there is this:

```
private ColorNotify DisabledColor;
```

But I've also tried the above field as a property instead like this:

```
private ColorNotify disabledColor;
public ColorNotify DisabledColor
{
    get
    { return disabledColor; }
    set
    { disabledColor = value; }
}
```

Also in MainPage.xaml.cs is this method:

```
private void Legend_Refreshed(object sender, Legend.RefreshedEventArgs Lgd_Refreshed_EvArgs)
{
    LayerItemViewModel layerItmViewMdl;
    ObservableCollection<LayerItemViewModel> layerItms;

    layerItmViewMdl = Lgd_Refreshed_EvArgs.LayerItem;
    Layer legendItemLyr = layerItmViewMdl.Layer; 

    if (!legendItemLyr.IsInitialized)
    { 
        DisabledColor = new ColorNotify();
        DisabledColor.BindableColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

In the MainPage.xaml I have this:

```
<esri:Legend 
        Map="{Binding ElementName=theMap}"
        LayerIDs="..." 
        Refreshed="Legend_Refreshed">
               <esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}" 
                                            Width="Auto" 
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" 
                                            Foreground="{Binding Source=DisabledColor, Path=BindableColor}">
                                        </CheckBox>
                                        <Slider Maximum="1"  
                                            Value="{Binding Layer.Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                            Width="80" />
                              </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
...
...
...
</esri:Legend>
```

Notice the XAML code above:

```
Foreground="{Binding Source=DisabledColor, Path=BindableColor}">
```

That didn't work.

I then tried this in the XAML:

```
Foreground="{Binding BindableColor}"
```

But that didn't work either
How do I bind the Foreground to the BindableColor property of the ColorNotify class? 
What should the XAML binding look like when binding to a INotifyPropertyChanged object? 
(Not through MVVM)

Comment: Make that field a property and do `DisabledColor.BindableColor` as your path

Comment: By the way, I've tried looking at this link for a similar question, but I didn't see a solution there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962149/how-can-i-bind-a-background-color-in-wpf-xaml?rq=1

Comment: NSGaga, do you mean I should make "ColorNotify DisabledColor" into a property? And should the binding be: "{Binding Path=DisabledColor.Bindablecolor}" ?

Comment: @NSGaga, I tried the following: 'Foreground="{Binding Path=DisabledColor.Bindablecolor}' and I made the property like this: 'private ColorNotify disabledColor;
        public ColorNotify DisabledColor
        {
            get { return disabledColor; }
            set { disabledColor = value; }
        }' But that did not work.

Comment: do `OnNotifyChanged` on `set` (and implement that properly) - see what others suggested - or let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Based on the below comment discussion, I think you should create an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) with a `Convert` method like this:

```
return new SolidColorBrush((bool)value ? Colors.Black : Colors.Red);
```

Let's say your `IValueConverter` class is named `InitializedColorConverter`, in a namespace you've added as xmlns `local`. Use it like this in the XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:InitializedColorConverter x:Key="InitializedColorConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
Foreground="{Binding IsInitialized, Converter = {StaticResource InitializedColorConverter}}"
```

**End Edit.** I'll leave the rest here as it may be useful for people with similar problems:

You'll need to change the field on `MainPage` to a public property:

```
public ColorNotify DisabledColor { get; private set; }
```

If you want the binding to update when `DisabledColor` itself is changed, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MainPage` (and this property) as well.

One of the simpler ways to get the correct value bound is to do it programmatically.  To do so, put a `Loaded` handler on your object:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}" 
          Width="Auto" 
          IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" 
          Loaded="MyCheckBoxLoaded">
```

And have your handler do something like this:

```
private void MyCheckBoxLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    cb.SetBinding(Control.ForegroundProperty,
new System.Windows.Data.Binding("DisabledColor.Bindablecolor") { Source = this });
}
```

The reason it may seem convoluted is that the `Source` needs to be your `MainPage`, and unfortunately in Silverlight, that's not as easy as it seems it ought to be.

If your `DisabledColor` will never change during the life of the page, you could keep it a private field (mark it `readonly` to ensure this is true) and do this instead in the handler:

```
cb.SetBinding(Control.ForegroundProperty,
new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Bindablecolor") { Source = this.DisabledColor });
```

Comment: I can't use the checkbox Loaded event. The "Legend" element shown in the XAML above will create many MapLayerElement objects (one for each map layer) which means that there will be many checkboxes. If I use the checkbox Loaded event, then I can't determine which checkbox is part of which MapLayerElement and which Map Layer is referenced by that MapLayerElement.

Comment: part 2, The Legend_Refreshed method of the "Legend" element is called each time a MapLayerElement is created. It is from within that method where I can use the Lgd_Refreshed_EvArgs to get a reference to the Map Layer so that I can determine if a Map layer has been initialized or not. Then, if it has not been initialized, I change the checkbox color.

Comment: If it makes any sense to have `DisabledColor`'s scope be an instance of `MainPage`, I don't see what's wrong with my code. I just noticed that the `DisabledColor` you actually create and set up in your code sample is a local variable in `Legend_Refreshed`. If the scope of `MainPage` makes sense, then use that; if you make it a property with `INotifyPropertyChanged` everywhere it should be, it doesn't matter that `Loaded` might happen before `Legend_Refreshed`. If that scope doesn't make sense, please specify what scope would (e.g. instance of `MapLayerElement`?).

Comment: Question, can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged on MainPage if I'm going to have many of the checkboxes bound to it?

Comment: Yes, you can have any number of things listening to one `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Sorry, our messages crossed. I had since changed Legend_Refreshed code to: DisabledColor = new ColorNotify(); DisabledColor.BindableColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); . So, it is not local to the method anymore.

Comment: Here is more of the code: 'private void Legend_Refreshed(object sender, Legend.RefreshedEventArgs Lgd_Refreshed_EvArgs)
        {
            LayerItemViewModel layerItmViewMdl;
            ObservableCollection<LayerItemViewModel> layerItms;

            layerItmViewMdl = Lgd_Refreshed_EvArgs.LayerItem;
            Layer legendItemLyr = layerItmViewMdl.Layer; 

            if (!legendItemLyr.IsInitialized)
            { 
                DisabledColor = new ColorNotify();
                DisabledColor.BindableColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            } ... }'

Comment: Question, So, since the 'DisabledColor.BindableColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);' needs to happen in the Legend_Refreshed method, should the scope be local to the method or to MainPage? The only reason I made it local to MainPage is because I didn't know how to bind from within a method.

Comment: Knowing that it happens in the `Legend_Refreshed` method is not enough data for me to know what scope it should be. Can more than one color exist simultaneously on the page? (if so, the scope should be more specific than the page) Can more than one color exist simultaneously on the `Legend`? (if so, the scope should be more speicific than the legend) Obviously only one color can exist on each instance of the `DataTemplate` I see. What type is that `DataTemplate` bound to? `LayerItemViewModel`, `Layer`, something else?

Comment: Depending on the answers to these questions, I might recommend a converter that takes a boolean (`IsInitialized`) and returns a color (e.g. `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`), which might be used like so: `Foreground="{Binding IsInitialized, Converter = {StaticResource InitializedColorConverter}}"`.  As an aside, if you're posting more than one or two lines of code, edit your question rather than posting a comment; comments don't allow nicely-formatted multi-line code.

Comment: Yes, each checkbox can be either black or red . There is an 'if' statement in the Legend_Refreshed event handler method that assigns the color depending on if the Map layer for that specific '<esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>' is initialized or not. (Appreciate your help VERY much)

Comment: Some checkboxes will be the default color, but checkboxes for MapLayerTemplate layers associated with unitiialized Map layers will be red.
So, if there are 10 Map layers, for instance, then the '<esri:Legend> element will have 10  '<esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>' . If two of those Map layers are uninitialized, then the two corresponding MapLayerTemplate's checkboxes will be red.

Comment: I've added something to the top of my answer, recommending a converter and showing you how to do it. I'm assuming that the bound datacontext of the `DataTemplate` is a `Layer`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change/init

```
private ColorNotify DisabledColor;
```

after View/ViewModel load then you would need to change this property to public and implement INotifyPropertyChange on it as well same as you have done on ColorNotify.

Comment: I'm not using MVVM. I changed the DisabledProperty field to public, but it did not work.