# Constantly changing the background of a button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have got a button on my window. by default the button's background color is blue. on clicking the button, color should be changed to red. but I see that background color is changing to red but it is not permanent.

here is the class code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool _highLow;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
           _highLow = false;

        }

        public bool RiskHighLowMedium
        {
            get { return _highLow; }
            set { _highLow= value ;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("BackGround");
            }
        }


         //background Dependency Property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty;


        /// <summary>
        /// static constructor
        /// </summary>
        static MainWindow()
        {
            BackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Background", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Background Dependency
        /// Property
        /// </summary>
        public Brush Background
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RiskHighLowMedium = true;
            Background = RiskHighLowMedium ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Background");
        }




        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    }
```

xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="backgrounChange.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="Button">


            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>

            <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RiskHighLowMedium }"  Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ Binding Path= Background}"/>
                </DataTrigger>


            </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" Style="{DynamicResource  CircleButton}" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would appreciate any sort of help here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I bind a background color in WPF/XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962149/how-can-i-bind-a-background-color-in-wpf-xaml)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not permanent'?

Comment: it's blinking. it is changing between blue and transparent.

Comment: @Sheridan: I do see while debugging that color is changed but when the control is actually visible, it's having the default color. any specific reason here?

Comment: Yes, that's because of an animation in the default `ControlTemplate` of the `Button`... I'll post an answer with an example shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can change the `Button.Background` value, the default `ControlTemplate` of the `Button` control defines an animation that animates the background of the `Button` between the official `Button.Background` value and another (light blue) colour. To get rid of this behaviour, you will have to define a new `ControlTemplate` for the `Button`. Here is a *very* basic example:

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RiskHighLowMedium}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...

<Button Width="50" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}" 
    Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>

...

bool _highLow = false;
public bool RiskHighLowMedium
{
    get { return _highLow; }
    set { _highLow = value; OnPropertyChanged("RiskHighLowMedium"); }
}

...

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RiskHighLowMedium = true;
}
```

Comment: Button Color is now null :(.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done but if you put those four pieces of code (that I adapted from *your* code) into a new WPF application as I did, you'll see that it does work.

Comment: @Sheridan, have you confirmed what happens when the button's visual state has focus combined with your trigger?  I'm guessing it would blink like the OP has seen, no?

Comment: Nope... it just remains red, as a plain old red `Border` would... there is no `Button VisualState` because the `Button ControlTemplate` has been set to a plain old `Border`... try it.