# WPF bind background color of DataGridTextColumn to color by row

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, background-color

Say I have a DataGrid with the following data:

```
John, Male
Mary, Female
Tony, Male
Sally, Female
```

The grid is bound to an ObservableCollection of Person model objects that implements INofifyPropertyChanged for the properties Person.Name and Person.Gender. I now want to bind the DataGridTextColumn's background color to the person's gender so that rows containing males are blue, and rows containing females are pink. Is it possible to do this by adding another property to the Person model like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (gender == "Male")
            {
                return Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                return Color.Pink;
            }
        }
    }
```

if so, how do I bind this to the row or column's background color? I already have bounded columns like this:

```
<DataGridColumn Header="Name" Binding={Binding Name} />
<DataGridColumn Header="Gender" Binding={Binding Gender} />
```

Comment: only `DataGridTextColumn` or whole row?

Comment: I'd like the entire row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `BackgroundColor` is of a `System.Windows.Media.Color` type, and not `System.Drawing.Color`, if you want to change background of the entire row you can alter `DataGrid.RowStyle` and bind `Background` property to `BackgroundColor` property

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Tried this, and it actually works great! But I noticed it doesn't work with the Forecolor. Ideally, I'd like to have bindings to both. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3685285 I've just tried it and it works also with `Foreground`. Just copy background `Setter` but make it set `Foreground` property and bind `Color` in exactly the same way, just to different colour property in your view model (say ForegroundColor).

Comment: Ah ok. It must be because I'm using the Modern UI extension, so I'll have to override the default styles somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement an IValueConverter to convert a String to a Brush. See http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/

```
public class StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (string)value;
        return new SolidColorBrush(val == "male" ? Colors.Blue : Colors.Pink);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In XAML, you'll want `<Window.Resources>` like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringToBrushConverter x:Key="stringToBrush" />
    <Style x:Key="MaleFemaleStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Gender, Converter={StaticResource stringToBrush}}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then apply the MaleFemaleStyle to your grid.

```
<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource MaleFemaleStyle}">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? How do I apply this to both columns, and how does xaml know I'm trying to set the Background color?

Comment: Sorry, I submitted before reviewing. The updates should do the right thing. The main thing is using the `IValueConverter` - this is best practice for MVVM. The rest is implementation details.

Comment: +1 Good read, but I think it's overly complicating things for me in this case. I'll keep it in mind for other uses.

Comment: I don't blame you. WPF has a "heavy-handed" feeling to it sometimes. It's better for testability and modularity, though, if those are important to you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sex}" Value="Male">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sex}" Value="Female">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```